# React Native project error in Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Well i am having trouble recently while importing the android directory of a react native project to android studio.

It used to work well before but now its throwing `This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 4.2 or newer.`

any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android view under Gradle Scrips, change two files, then re-sync gradle.

1. build.grade (Project):
   `classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")`
2. gradle-wrapper.properties:
   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip`

I just encountered the same issue and solved it using the above fix. You may find this thread useful as well: [Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678785/android-support-plugin-for-intellij-idea-or-android-studio-cannot-open-this-pr)