# My Flutter app cloned from the GitHub doesn't run and show these errors. I'm new to flutter. I changed Sdk version to 30, 31 but it didn't work

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, github

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

```
 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
 Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Rasula Wathsara\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\41a83d0cf61e3d2ab42ea706b65148ab\transformed\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

 The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
 dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
 Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
 AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Rasula Wathsara\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\bb9a53f8c4dc071c681fa071739dc70b\transformed\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: You need to update the gradle version at `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Try using version `7.0.2`

Comment: It is already in 7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

[Detailed StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67709605/13533028)

This usually happens when you're opening someone else's project after unzipping it and your current Android Studio Version is older to the version the project was compiled in.

The way to solve it is

```
Go to Help and about to see your android studio version
go to File>Project Structure> and set your Android Gradle Plugin version to your android studio version
Change the Gradle version to the one you usually use.
```

Build the project and it should run without any errors

Answer (score 0):

app/src/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
}
```

You can try this.