# The version of the Android cannot open this project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin

When i run my project i l've got this error :

```
This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2021.2.1 or newer.

The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.
```

I update all dependencies but stil the same error how can i fix it ?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA? Have you tried updating it?

Comment: Android Studio and yes i try to update it but the same problem :(

Comment: *2021.2.1* is the *Chipmunk* release: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#agp-studio-compatibility so you'll probably need to make sure you're using that. There's some info about solving this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62678785 - it's specifically an incompatibility between the bundled Android plugin in the IDE and the version of the Android gradle plugin you're using, apparently: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4405168877202 Your second warning is a separate thing, just telling you not to use the `android-extensions` plugin anymore