# How to solve android studio loading project?

Tags: android-studio

Android studio says
"This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2021.1.1 or newer."

Comment: Hello.  I think the `r` tag is misleading here - can you please edit the tags to be more appropriate, this will draw attention from people likely to know the answer.

Comment: i think this link help you...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678785/android-support-plugin-for-intellij-idea-or-android-studio-cannot-open-this-pr